# HTML5 video stream only to player

Tags: php, html, video, streaming

I am trying to make my videos on website harder to download, but failed with one point. Solution works good if your goal is to kill video link after 15 mins (enough for user to see video).

But also i want let player get this streaming into HTML5 video player, but don't let user to download it by putting video source link in new tab.

I tried to made this link one-time-working, but the problem is that HTML5 player connects to streaming script more than one time.

So probably there is any solution how in my streaming script i can check if script forced to open directly or forced by HTML5 player? Or maybe there is another way how to block direct opening of this script?

Streaming script:

```
<?php

[...]    

if (!empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['token'])){
    if (strtotime($array['created']) > strtotime('-15 minutes')) {

    $file = 'Z:/home/localhost/www/mvc/video/' . $_GET['id'];

    $fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');
    $size   = filesize($file); // File size
    $length = $size;           // Content length
    $start  = 0;               // Start byte
    $end    = $size - 1;       // End byte

   header('Content-type: video/mp4');

   //header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
   header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        $c_start = $start;
        $c_end   = $end;
        list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{
        $range  = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] :       $size;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    $start  = $c_start;
    $end    = $c_end;
    $length = $end - $start + 1;
    fseek($fp, $start);
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}

header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);
$buffer = 1024 * 32;

while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {
    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
    }
    set_time_limit(0);
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);
    flush();
}

fclose($fp);
exit();
}
else {
echo 'Token is closed';
}
}
else {
echo 'Denied';
}
```

Player looks like this:

```
<video width="640" height="480" preload controls>
<source src="http://localhost/mvc/video/video.php?id=video.mp4&token=0c9eb340fa59db2accf61b16663c79b1" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after two days of cruel fighting i finally found the decision.

To achieve this goal (let HTML5 video player stream video, but block direct download with link), i changed this:

```
if (!empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['token'])){
if (strtotime($array['created']) > strtotime('-15 minutes'))
{
stream video...
}
```

to this:

```
if (!empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['token'])){
if (strtotime($array['created']) > strtotime('-15 minutes') && $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'] == true) {
stream...
}
```

Sure this is not 100% guarantee to protect your video, but now it is harder to download.